# How does using a neutral tone developer affect warmtone paper?

Tags: printing, developing, darkroom, warmth

If you're using a developer that produces neutral tones with paper specifically labeled as Warm Tone paper, does it not produce a warm tone with that paper, or must you use a warm tone developer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, a neutral tone developer has no effect on the tone of paper developed in it.

By comparison, a warm tone developer will tend to "warm up" any paper -- neutral paper will get slightly warm, cold tone paper will change toward neutral, and warm tone paper will get warmer.

Similarly, a cold tone developer will tend to change the tone of papers to make them "colder" -- but the "tone" that's native to a paper is defined as what it shows in a neutral tone developer (Dektol or D-72 are pretty much the standard here).